# How to filter a stream of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, filtering, signal-processing

Im trying to implement a filter for sensor readings on a Raspi. I get a constant stream of data from the sensors that I want to filter using my filter code. I tried to emulate the sort of readings I would get from a sensor by generating random numbers in my rangen code. The issue is that for some reason I cannot see any output from the filter and I dont even know if it works. Below are the codes for generating a random stream of data and the filter. Am I emulating the sensor readings right?(Note: Im not particularly concerned about the values, I just want a random stream of data that I can keep reading and filter)

Generating random data

```
# generate random integer values, Filename: Rangen.py
from random import seed
from random import randint
from time import sleep
# seed random number generator
seed(1)
# generate some integers
def rangen():
    value = randint(0, 100)
    return value

while True:
    data = rangen()
    sleep(0.1)
```

and here is the filter

```
from time import sleep
from statistics import mean
from Rangen import data

def AplhaTrimmedfilter(windowsize,alpha, sensordata):
    data_list = []
    Flag = True
    while Flag:
        if len(data_list)<windowsize:
            data_list.append(sensordata)
            print("data added")
            sleep(0.0010)
            break
    if len(data_list)==windowsize:
        sorted_data = data_list.sort()     
        sliced_data = sorted_data[(windowsize/2):windowsize-alpha+(alpha/2)]
        alphamean = statistics.mean(sliced_data) #sum(a) / len(a)
        data_list = []
        print(data_list)
    return alphamean

AlphaTrimmedfilter(5,2,data)
```

I want to take 5 values from the generated data, sort them, slice them and avergae them and display at the end. I dont understand if I implemented this right because the output on the console shows nothing. Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: As MisterMiyagi suggested, I used generators to tackle the issue with filtering and I iterated over the generator object using [[item] for item in filtered_data] but now I have a weird TypeError 'Float' object is not iterable. How would I fix this issue? I think this might be due to the type of data I pass into the filter(which is mostly float). Here is the code for the modified filter based on MisterMiyagi's answer:

```
def alpha_mean(window, alpha):
    cut = alpha//2
    data = sorted(window)[cut:-cut]
    result = sum(data)/len(data)
    return result

def alphatrimmer(window_size, alpha, sensor_stream):
    window = []
    for item in sensor_stream:
        window.append(item)
        if len(window) >= window_size:
            break
    yield alpha_mean(window, alpha)

    for item in sensor_stream:
        window.pop(0)
        window.append(item)
        yield alpha_mean(window,alpha)
```

Comment: How are you running this? Your first code snippet just enters an infinite loop without any output, the second just calls a function without any output. The two don't interact at all.

Comment: Take note that `data` passed to ``AplhaTrimmedfilter`` is a constant. The line ``data_list.append(sensordata)`` just keeps on adding this constant again and again. Have you considered making ``sensordata`` and ``rangen`` a generator/iterator?

Comment: I import the varaible 'data' from the file Rangen. Rangen continioulsy spits out random data, Im storing these values in data variable and appending them to the list 'data_list'. Is that not the right way to do it? I was trying to emulate sensor readings from the Rangen code.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I would very much like to keep these two files apart, in the first file Im only trying to emulate how I recieve my sensor readings and I want it to keep generating random numbers forever.

Comment: You cannot import from ``Rangen``, because the module will never finish initialising! Also, if you import a name from a module (``from Rangen import data``) it has the value *at the time of import*. Changes in the external module will not be visible under the imported name.

Comment: As said, ``rangen`` should ideally be a generator.

Comment: I see, so there is not a stream of data but only a single one that is read into my filter? How could I create this generator? I want to be able to read values one by one into my filter as they are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's native equivalent of streams are iterators. You can create your own iterator by writing a generator. For example, we can turn your `rangen` *function producing one value* into a *generator function producing many values*.

```
# stream.py
import random

random.seed(1)

def random_stream():
    """Generator producing a stream of random numbers"""
    while True:      # generators can produce values indefinitely...
        value = random.randint(0, 100)
        yield value  # ... by yield'ing them
```

Among other things, iterators/generators can be consumed by `for` statements. You can test this on the Python console:

```
>>> from stream import random_stream
>>> data = random_stream()   # note: the generator is called using ()
>>> for idx, item in enumerate(data):
...     if idx >= 3: break
...     print(idx, ':', item)
0 : 17
1 : 72
2 : 97
```

---

A function that consumes such a stream ideally is *also* a generator - instead of applying a fixed window once, it moves a window over the stream. This allows to seamlessly consume the entire stream, no matter how long it is.

Ideally, you split the tracking of the window and the computation at each window position. Notably, the latter is *not* a generator - it just works on a single window state.

```
def alpha_mean(window, alpha):
    """Compute the mean for a given window and alpha"""
    size = len(window)
    data = sorted(window)[size//2:size - (alpha // 2)]
    return sum(data) / len(data)


def alpha_trim(window_size, alpha, sensor_stream):
    """Produce a trimmed stream based on the ``sensor_stream`` data"""
    window = []  # note: a collections.deque is more efficient for very large windows
    # fill the first window
    for item in sensor_stream:
        window.append(item)
        if len(window) >= window_size:
            break
    yield alpha_mean(window, alpha)
    # advance the window as new data comes in
    for item in sensor_stream:
        # "move" the window by discarding the oldest value
        window.pop(0)
        window.append(item)
        yield alpha_mean(window, alpha)
```

The `alpha_trim` is a generator that also takes a generator. You can test this again in the Python console:

```
>>> data = alpha_trim(5, 2, rangen())
>>> for idx, item in enumerate(data):
...     if idx >= 5: break
...     print(idx, ':', item)
0 : 52.0
1 : 52.0
2 : 47.5
3 : 47.5
4 : 60.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, MisterMiyagi. I think I understand what you mean by the generators and iterators now.

Comment: MisterMiyagi, the code works but when I try to print the data it returns, it prints out "generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000078" something like that. Is this because I need to iterate over the generator object?

Comment: @LeafTeaNeko Exactly. You must either iterate over the generator, or call the ``next`` builtin on it.